# How to specify react-native-firebase/app and react-native-firebase/crashlytics in podspec file of an expo module

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, podspec, expo-module

I have created an expo module and I have added `react-native-firebase/app` and `react-native-firebase/crashlytics` under devDependencies in `package.json`. Now, I need to add these dependencies in `Podspec` file of the same module. Because, when I integrate the expo module, it should automatically download `react-native-firebase/app` and `react-native-firebase/crashlytics` on `pod install`. Please help me on how to add dependencies into podspec of an expo module.